# Special inequality

Tags: inequality

How to prove the following inequality: $$(a x-b y-c z-d t)^2\geq (a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2) (x^2-y^2-z^2-t^2),$$ if we know $$a^2\geq (b^2+c^2+d^2),$$ $$x^2\geq (y^2+z^2+t^2).$$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error. Inequality is obvious, sorry.

Comment: Mind answering your own question so I can see how?  Wouldn't mind learning from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this a special case of Aczel's inequaliyt http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Aczel's_Inequality

Comment: Yes. It is also known as triangle inequality in Minkowski spacetime for timelike vectors...

Comment: There are many proofs to it, can't you find one?